# Is there a way to document cuda's ".cu" file use doxygen

Tags: cuda, doxygen

As the cuda's ".cu" file is basically c, Is there a way we can use doxygen to generate documentation for ".cu" files? I noticed that NVIDIA use doxygen to generate cuda's docuementation. However when I use doxygen, the ".cu" files are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this is your problem: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_file_patterns

> If the value of the INPUT tag contains directories, you
>   can use the FILE_PATTERNS tag to specify one or more wildcard patterns
>   (like *.cpp and *.h ) to filter out the source-files in the directories.
>   If left blank the following patterns are tested:
>   .c *.cc *.cxx *.cpp *.c++ *.d *.java *.ii *.ixx *.ipp *.i++ *.inl *.h *.hh
>   .hxx *.hpp *.h++ *.idl *.odl *.cs *.php *.php3 *.inc *.m *.mm *.dox *.py .f90 *.f *.vhd
>   *.vhdl

Comment: Based on another report it might also be useful to check the EXTENSION_MAPPING setting

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else is coming along and reading this with the same problem, what you need to do is this:

1. Add `*.cu` to `FILE_PATTERNS`.
2. Add `cu=c++` `EXTENSION_MAPPING`.

You can find documentation for both options [here](http://cudpp.googlecode.com/svn-history/r284/tags/1.1.1/cudpp/cudpp.doxygen).

If you're using the Windows Doxygen GUI frontend, `FILE_PATTERNS` is on the `Input` page and `EXTENSION_MAPPING` is on the `Project` page.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `cu=C++ cuh=C++ cuhpp=C++`? Also, do I set FILE_PATTERNS to the super-long-list-of-everything and also the `*.cu`, or do I only set it to `*.cu` with doxygen appending the rest?