# Documenting cuda files with doxygen

Tags: cuda, doxygen

I followed this http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_file_patterns , added *.cu to the PATTERN_FILES. But cuda files are still not documented.

The output when generating documentation:

- cuda files ->"reading"
- others (*.cpp *.c *.h) -> "preprocessing" then "parsing".

My Doxyfile is pretty basic (almost the default one) and version is 1.8.9.1.

Comment: Did you have a look at EXTENSION_MAPPING ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Albert, i just added:
`EXTENSION_MAPPING = cu=C`, don't know why others posts didn't mention it [Is there a way to document cuda's ".cu" file use doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047081/is-there-a-way-to-document-cudas-cu-file-use-doxygen).

And now i get the good output for cuda files: "preprocessing/parsing" and documentation seems to be well generated.

Thank you albert.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think in the past the default handling might have been C for all files. Probably this has changed (for sure I know that something changed regarding text defaults).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `cu=C++ cuh=C++ cuhpp=C++` ?