# How can I make Doxygen aware of CUDA kernel calls?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, doxygen

I'm trying to document a project written in CUDA C using Doxygen. The documentation works fine. However the caller graphs does not include kernel calls as in `GPU_foo<<<1,1>>>()`.

For example, in this simple example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*!
 * @brief global hello foo
 */
__global__ void global_hello(void){

printf("Hello\n");

}


/*!
 * @brief CPU hello foo
 */
void hello(void){

printf("Hello\n");
}

/*!
 * @brief main
 */
int main(){

 hello();

 global_hello<<<1,1>>>();

return 0;
}
```

With a corresponding Doxyfile:

```
PROJECT_NAME = TEST
PROJECT_NUMER = 2.1

OUTPUT_LANGUAGE = English
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
FILE_PATTERNS = *.cpp *.h *.c *.cu
RECURSIVE = NO 
PDF_HYPERLINKS = YES
USE_PDFLATEX   = YES
HAVE_DOT = YES
CALL_GRAPH = YES
CALLER_GRAPH = YES
```

When looking at the generated documentation the call graph looks like this:

```
main -----> hello
```

Instead of the desired:

```
      ------> global_hello
    /
main
    \
      ------> hello
```

How can I make Doxygen aware of CUDA kernel calls?

The problem is that Doxygen does not know that a line containing "<<< >>>" is a function call. I do not need the call graph to make a distinction between function calls and kernel calls. It is enough if the parser considers the kernel as normal function calls.

Summarizing. Is there a way to tell Doxygen to interpret the lines with <<<>>> as function calls?
Some suggested to change the internal parser method of Doxygen, how should this be done?

Comment: what if you add a specific `EXTENSION_MAPPING` to your doxyfile, such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047081/is-there-a-way-to-document-cudas-cu-file-use-doxygen)

Comment: I believe that by default Doxygen treats unknown extensions as C. However adding "EXTENSION_MAPPING = cu=c++" or cu=c yields the same result, a proper documentation of the function but an incorrect caller graph.

Answer (score 1):

If doxygen doesn't recognize the CUDA functions, there's not much you can do:

Citing the [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcallgraph):

> **Note**
>       The completeness (and correctness) of the call graph depends on the doxygen code parser which is not perfect.

And the code parser of doxygen is not easily extensible.

Comment: And what would be the path to make this? I imagine I am not the only one trying to make this kind of call graphs.

Is there a way to simply tell Doxygen to somehow ignore the <<< >>> operator?

Comment: @user2511417: as I said, "the code parser of doxygen is not easily extensible", which means that you have to change the way doxygens code parser works internally, by changing its source code.